# Trouble utilizing the GetDIBits function within ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, api, winapi

I have the Ruby code below, I am using windows API calls and I should be able to use the function GetDIBits to retrieve an array of RGB values from the bitmap that I have created, to be used for AI processing. I need to give the GetDIBits function a BITMAPINFO structure as well as a few other variables. I should be okay with the other variables, but how do you create a structure in ruby (using the Windows API) that can be used for this function?

Please see below code

If you can complete the GetDIBits function so that I can retrive a array of RGB values, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks
Martin

```
def getscreen()

width = Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetSystemMetrics",["L"],"L").call(0)
height = Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetSystemMetrics",["L"],"L").call(1)

#Get desktop DC, create a compatible dc, create a comaptible bitmap and select into compatible dc.
hddc = Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetDC",["L"],"L").call(Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetDesktopWindow",[],"L").call)
hcdc = Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","CreateCompatibleDC",["L"],"L").call(hddc)
hbitmap = Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","CreateCompatibleBitmap",["L","L","L"],"L").call(hddc,width,height)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","SelectObject",["L","L"],"L").call(hcdc,hbitmap)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","BitBlt",["L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","P"],"L").call(hcdc,0,0,width,height,hddc,0,0,"SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT")

#save hbitmap to stream of byte as you mentioned
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","GetDIBits",["L","L","L","L","L","L","P"],"L").call(hcdc,hbitmap,1,1200,0,"DIB_RGB_COLORS")

pixelarray = Array.new
#Need a .call to fill the pixelarray array

Win32API.new("User32.dll","ReleaseDC",["L","L"],"L").call(Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetDesktopWindow",[],"L").call,hddc)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","DeleteDC",["L"],"L").call(hcdc)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","DeleteObject",["L"],"L").call(hbitmap)

#Print screen width and height
puts "Screen width: #{width}"
puts "Screen height: #{height}"

end
```

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this code.  I'll see if I can get it working myself.  What is the end goal?  Where does the image come from?

Comment: The end goal is to have an array in ruby with the values of pixels that make up the screen. The image comes from the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems to get some data, though I haven't looked at carefully enough to tell if it is colors from the screen:

```
require 'Win32API'

module Foo
  GetSystemMetrics = Win32API.new "User32.dll", "GetSystemMetrics", ["L"], "L"
  GetDC = Win32API.new "User32.dll", "GetDC", ["L"], "L"
  GetDesktopWindow = Win32API.new "User32.dll", "GetDesktopWindow", [], "L"
  CreateCompatibleDC = Win32API.new "Gdi32.dll", "CreateCompatibleDC", ["L"], "L"
  CreateCompatibleBitmap = Win32API.new "Gdi32.dll", "CreateCompatibleBitmap", ["L","L","L"], "L"
  SelectObject = Win32API.new "Gdi32.dll","SelectObject", ["L","L"], "L"
  BitBlt = Win32API.new "Gdi32.dll","BitBlt", ["L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L"], "L"
  CAPTUREBLT = 0x40000000 
  SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020
  GetDIBits = Win32API.new "Gdi32.dll","GetDIBits", ["L","L","L","L","P","P","L"], "L"
  DIB_RGB_COLORS = 0
  BI_RGB = 0

  def self.getscreen
    width = GetSystemMetrics.call 0
    height = GetSystemMetrics.call 1    
    puts "Screen width: #{width}"
    puts "Screen height: #{height}"

    desktop_handle = GetDesktopWindow.call
    raise "GetDesktopWindow failed" if desktop_handle == 0
    hddc = GetDC.call desktop_handle
    raise "Get DC failed." if hddc == 0
    hcdc = CreateCompatibleDC.call hddc
    raise "CreateCompatibleDC failed" if hcdc == 0

    hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap.call hddc, width, height
    raise "CreateCompatibleBitmap failed" if hbitmap == 0
    result = SelectObject.call hcdc, hbitmap
    raise "SelectObject failed" if result == 0   # not sure if this is right

    result = BitBlt.call hcdc, 0, 0, width, height, hddc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT
    raise "BitBlt failed" if result == 0

    SelectObject.call hcdc, 0   # attempt to deselect the bitmap because GetDIBits requires it?

    size_in_bytes = width*height*4
    bitmap_info = [40, #biSize
      width,
      height,
      1, #biPlanes
      32, #biBitCount
      BI_RGB, #biCompression
      size_in_bytes,
      2000, #biXPelsPerMeter: not used?
      2000, #biYPelsPerMeter: not used?
      0, # biClrUsed
      0 # biClrImportant
    ].pack("LLLSSLLLLLL") #+ [0,0,0,0].pack("LLLL")

    buffer = (" " * size_in_bytes).force_encoding("BINARY")

    result = GetDIBits.call hcdc, hbitmap, 0, height, buffer, bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS
    raise "GetDIBits failed." if result == 0
    puts "Number of scan lines copied: #{result}"
    puts "buffer contents: " + buffer.strip.inspect[0,100] + " ..."
    puts "First pixel = %02x,%02x,%02x,%02x" % [buffer[0].ord, buffer[1].ord, buffer[2].ord, buffer[3].ord]

    return buffer
  end
end

Foo.getscreen
```

The output when I run it with ruby 1.9.2p180 in Windows is:

```
Screen width: 1366
Screen height: 768
Number of scan lines copied: 768
buffer contents: "\x0F\f\a\xFF\x0F\f\a\xFF\x0F\f\a\xFF\x0F\f\a\xFF\x0F\f\a\xFF\x
0F\f\a\xFF\x0F\f\a\xFF\x0F\f\a\xFF\x0 ...
First pixel = 0f,0c,07,ff
```

Let me know if you have any questions about what I'm doing here.

Comment: Thats beautiful and looks like it could really work... can you get the pixel hex values into a 3 digit array of 3 values (RGB)? Either that or a single value for the pixels colour? I'll look at this tomorrow morning (just off to bed) but I may be able to retrieve a value such as the one above from these hex values. Cheers

Comment: Looked over it again.. off to bed now but looks like an answer that will work. Thank you so much for your time David.. very much appriciated - Martin

Comment: Once you verify that this code works, I would really appreciate an upvote and an acceptance of the answer.  Just click the up arrow and click the check box.

Comment: Awesome. All yesterday's evening spent on searching such snippet in Python – no result. And I know why.